# Git2go: Simulate git checkout and an immediate git push

Tags: git, go, libgit2

How can I achieve the following using `git2go`.

```
$ git checkout -b feature_branch_name
... edit files, add and commit ...
$ git push -u origin feature_branch_name
```

I'm stuck here:

```
branch, err = repo.CreateBranch("test", headCommit, false, 
    signature, "Test branch that I was to push immediately")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have the following now, it creates the branch and point to the correct branch, but I can't get it to update the working directory just like `git checkout` does:

```
head, err := repository.Head()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

headCommit, err := repository.LookupCommit(head.Target())
if err != nil {
    return err
}

_, err = cs.repository.CreateBranch(name, headCommit, false)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

_, err = cs.repository.References.CreateSymbolic("HEAD","refs/heads/"+name, true, "headOne")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

opts := &git.CheckoutOpts{
    Strategy: git.CheckoutSafe | git.CheckoutRecreateMissing,
}
if err := repository.CheckoutHead(opts); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

I think I'm struggling with the **checkout options now**.

I'm still working on the push part.

Comment: What error are you seeing ?

Comment: Please see the updates on the question.

Comment: Why are you doing a checkout at all?  `git checkout -b` (despite the name) merely creates a new branch and sets `HEAD` to that.  What do you want your checkout to do?

Comment: @Sthe thanks for the update - still not sure what error you get?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, but you know when you run `git checkout <somebranch>`, the files on the working directory get updated based on what on the working tree of that branch (I believe)? That's the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working. Here is the code if anyone is wondering about the same thing:

**git checkout**

```
head, err := repository.Head()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

headCommit, err := repository.LookupCommit(head.Target())
if err != nil {
    return err
}

_, err = cs.repository.CreateBranch(name, headCommit, false)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

_, err = cs.repository.References.CreateSymbolic("HEAD","refs/heads/"+name, true, "headOne")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

opts := &git.CheckoutOpts{
    Strategy: git.CheckoutSafe | git.CheckoutRecreateMissing,
}
if err := repository.CheckoutHead(opts); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

**git push**

```
// Get remote
remote, err := repo.Remotes.Lookup("origin")
if err != nil {
    remote, err = repo.Remotes.Create("origin", repo.Path())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}

// Get the branch
branch, err := repo.Branch()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// Get the name
branchName, err := branch.Name()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := remote.Push([]string{"refs/heads/"+branchName}, &git.PushOptions{}); err != nil {
    return err
}

return nil
```

Depending on what version of `git2go` you are using, this might also be helpful: http://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2014/git2go-tutorial/ (great article)

Things have changed quite a bit since then though.

Thank you